# Logic of Access Tokens

Tags: swift, api, token

I'm learning making API Requests from a mobile app.

An API that I am using, returns an access_token, expires_in and refresh_token when making a login request.

I'm trying to understand the whole logic behind the access token idea, been looking all over the internet and cannot find a good example nor a good explanation.

As far as I am aware,

The best method for making API requests is:

1) Store the expires_in internally on the device
2) On every request first check if the token is expired
3) If so, then request a new one using the refresh token
4) Otherwise make the request

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Your flow is basically correct.
If it is a JWT token, you can decode it. Inside you can find some properties, check [here](https://jwt.io).
What you can do is use the `iat` property of the token, this contains the time when the token was issued (you can't rely on the received date from the WS) add the expiration time to that date, this will be the expiration date.
If you are using Alamofire is pretty easy, there are 2 protocols:

- `RequestAdapter`
- `RequestRetrier`

By using a combination of the two can you easily refresh your token, in the request adapter you can throw an error if the token is expired, in the retrier you can intercept this specific error and make a refresh token request.
It is explained [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adapting-and-retrying-requests).